# Sublime Text 2 to MySQL Database Connection not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to get new customer account creation details to be transferred to mySQL database, however when ever I press the "create" button, it comes up with an error saying: 'Safari can't find the file. No file exists at the address /User/Filip/Desktop/Client_Information.php/.'

I have my whole html and php script in a .html file on my desktop, and I think it has to be uploaded somewhere?

Here is my php code for send and receive from the database:

```
<?php

$dbhost = "my_host_name";
$dbuser = "my_username";
$dbpass = "my_password";
$dbdata = "database_name";

if(!mysql_connect($name, $host, $user)){
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}

else {
    $data = mysql_select_db($dbdata);
    if(!$data)
    {
        die('Could not use: '.$dbdata);
    }
}

$insert = "INSERT INTO Client_Information (first_name, last_name, email_address, phone_number, password, confirm_password) VALUES('".$_POST["first_name"]."', '".$_POST["last_name"]."', '".$_POST["email_address"]."', '".$_POST["phone_number"]."', '".$_POST["password"]."', '".$_POST["confirm_password"]."')";

var_dump($insert);
$handle = mysql_query($insert);
var_dump($handle);

?>
```

And here is the beginning of my html code for all the inputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="login-block">
        <h1>Create Account</h1>
        <form action="recieve_Client_Information.php" method="post">
          <input type="Text" value="" placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" />
          <input type="Text" value="" placeholder="Last Name" id="last_name" />
          <input type="Email" value="" placeholder="E-mail Address" id="email_address" />
          <input type="Number" value="" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone_number" />
          <input type="Password" value="" placeholder="Password" id="password" />
          <input type="Password" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirm_password" />
          <button>Create</button> 
        </form>
    </div>
</head>
```

Can anyone perhaps spot any errors? Or is the code that I need to add or a place I need to upload my scripts to?

I'm using a MacBook Pro, I've tried FileZilla but it does not work for me.

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: You can't read php file on your local machine if you don't have MAMP or something like that installed. Your browser cannot interpretate php.

You have to upload both files on your webserver.

Moreover your html is all wrong, where is the body ? :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought the problem is. FileZilla doesent work for me, so would you perhaps say I should download MAMP and try there?

Comment: I didn't include the body, I do have it!

Comment: I would like to help you, but here there are too many things to fix. I'll try to fix your code, but where is your db ? on a webserver ?

Comment: Thank You :) Yes, my database is on a server :)

Comment: The form has to be  inside the body, not inside the head tag of your page... I suggest you to don't store password on your db without hashing them... <button>Create</button> I don't think it will work :)

Comment: Give me 20 minutes... :)

Comment: Thanks alot, I'm waiting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all I've to tell you this code is not intended to use in production website or app, it's intended only to study or for example.**

There are many things to fix before use it in the "real" world:

- MySQL is deprecated, instead use MySQLi or PDO to connect to your DB
- There isn't any validate on the form (email phone number etc)
- Password stored in a DB without any pre-validation, without any
  hashing and without any minimuns requirement like here is something 
  ridiculous, please don't consider to use it for real.
- No characters escape, no control on code injection...
- No security at all

I hope you'll understand what I mean. Anyway, in this way your code will work:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1,IE=edge" />
    <title>Example for my friend Filip</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="login-block">
        <h1>Create Account</h1>
        <form action="insert_data.php" method="post">
          <input type="Text" value="" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" />
          <input type="Text" value="" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" />
          <input type="Email" value="" placeholder="E-mail Address" name="email_address" />
          <input type="Number" value="" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone_number" />
          <input type="Password" value="" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
          <input type="Password" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm_password" />
          <button>Create</button> 
        </form>
    </div>
</body>


<!-- DON'T USE THIS CODE ON REAL WEBSITE, IT'S UNSAFE -->
```

insert_data.php

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'your_host');
define('DB_NAME', 'your_db_name');
define('DB_USER','your_db_username');
define('DB_PASSWORD','your_db_password');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

$insert = "INSERT INTO Client_Information (first_name, last_name, email_address, phone_number, password, confirm_password) VALUES('".$_POST["first_name"]."', '".$_POST["last_name"]."', '".$_POST["email_address"]."', '".$_POST["phone_number"]."', '".$_POST["password"]."', '".$_POST["confirm_password"]."')";

var_dump($insert);
$handle = mysql_query($insert);
var_dump($handle);

?>

<!-- DON'T USE THIS CODE ON REAL WEBSITE, IT'S UNSAFE -->
```

You've to validate what people will insert in your form, you've to check if the first password is equal to the second one, you've to hash the password and you have to avoid the possibility of code injection.

I'll suggest you to consider a good course or to use a CMS like Wordpress to manage your users.

Both the files I gave you has to be on your webserver, so you have to connect to your webserver with filezilla and upload them.

Comment: Okay so I have tried it, but when ever I type in the data, nothing appears in mySQL database :/

Comment: Okay, database works but no values get input into it. Here is what comes up: string(142) "INSERT INTO Client_Information (first_name, last_name, email_address, phone_number, password, confirm_password) VALUES('', '', '', '', '', '')" bool(false)

Comment: Look the input: <input type="Text" value="" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" /> Change ID with NAME (like mine).

change id="first_name" in name="first_name"

and let me know.

Comment: Yes thats perfect. Works great! The only problem I'm having now is that I had a little image in front of the placeholder in the input box, and when I change the id to name, they just disappear. In my CSS I have this: .login-block input#first_name {

Comment: add also id="first_name" in the input tag... so it will become <input type="Text" value="" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" id="first_name" />

Comment: THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP :)))